# What is the fastest way to evaluate Pixel colors of 4 points using c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, automation

I am trying to make an auto clicker app. Initially I input the coordinates of 4 points and after that my app will click on each point when the red color of that point becomes lower than a certain threshold.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
int main() {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4;
    cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2 >> x3 >> y3 >> x4 >> y4;

    while(1) {
        evaluate(x1, y1);
        evaluate(x2, y2);
        evaluate(x3, y3);
        evaluate(x4, y4);
    }
}
```

And the evaluate method is given below:

```
void evaluate(int x, int y) {
    int red = GetRValue(GetPixel(hdc, x, y));
    //printf("%d ", red);
    if(red<=threshold) {
        mouseMoveTo(x, y);
        mouseLeftClick();
    }
}
```

The mouseMoveTo method is as follows:

```
void mouseMoveTo (int toX, int toY) {
     double dx = toX*(65535.0f / screenRes_width);
     double dy = toY*(65535.0f / screenRes_height);

     // movement stuff
     INPUT Input = {0};
     Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
     Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE|MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
     Input.mi.dx = LONG(dx);
     Input.mi.dy = LONG(dy);
     ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

The mouseLeftClick function:

```
void mouseRightClick () {
     INPUT Input = {0};

     // right down
     Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
     Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
     ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));

     // right up
     ::ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
     Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
     Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
     ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

But this code is very slow. I found some solutions online but could not improve the performance much. It takes about 100ms to complete evaluating the four points. Is there any way I can do it faster? Will evaluating each point in a separate thread increase its performance? If so, should I use c++11 std::thread or POSIX threads to get better performance?

Comment: I would suggest using a profiler to figure out which calls are causing the delays. Using multiple threads has a good chance of making it faster I think. But keep in mind that you'll always be at least one frame (perhaps 10~20ms) behind. BTW, I used to use AutoHotkey for this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you think AutoHotKey will be fast enough for my application?

Comment: To evaluate a color to RGB , bit shifting is the fastest .

Comment: @TanmoyKrishnaDas With just a single thread, I don't think it'll make a difference.